# Stacking 3 different columns on 1 barplot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I would like to stack theese 3 columns but I was unable to do so because their values contain$ next to them. I was trying to do it using as.numeric but with no effect. Could someone please help me fix this?

Here is my code:

```
ggplot(dane, aes(rodzajSportu, fill=(as.numeric(calkowiteZarobki))))+
  geom_bar(fill="green",position="stack")+
  geom_bar(aes(rodzajSportu, fill=as.numeric(wynagrodzenie)), fill="red",position="stack")+
  geom_bar(aes(rodzajSportu, fill=as.numeric(inneZarobki)), fill="gold",position="stack")+
  theme(text = element_text(size=15),axis.text.x = element_text(angle=90, hjust=1))+
  labs(title = "Diagram ", x="Rodzaj Sportu", y="Liczba zawodnikow")
```

I would be thankful if you could tell me how to either stack them or at least group them on one chart.

Here is sample data as requested:

```
structure(list(Rank = c(55L, 95L, 60L, 48L, 93L, 27L, 75L, 47L, 
91L, 97L, 74L, 84L, 24L, 37L, 37L, 57L, 30L, 70L, 40L, 80L), 
    Name = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 
    13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 18L, 17L, 19L, 20L, 23L, 24L), .Label = c("Aaron Rodgers", 
    "Adam Scott", "Adrian Gonzalez", "Albert Pujols", "Alex Rodriguez", 
    "Alfonso Soriano", "Amar'e Stoudemire", "Barry Zito", "Blake Griffin", 
    "Branden Albert", "Brandon Marshall", "Canelo Alvarez", "Carl Crawford", 
    "Carlos Dunlap", "Carmelo Anthony", "CC Sabathia", "Chris Bosh", 
    "Chris Paul", "Cliff Lee", "Cole Hamels", "Cristiano Ronaldo", 
    "Dale Earnhardt Jr.", "Darrelle Revis", "David Ortiz", "Derek Jeter", 
    "Deron Williams", "Derrick Rose", "Dirk Nowitzki", "Drew Brees", 
    "Dwight Howard", "Dwyane Wade", "Eli Manning", "Felix Hernandez", 
    "Fernando Alonso", "Fernando Torres", "Floyd Mayweather", 
    "Franck RibĂ©ry", "Gareth Bale", "Geno Atkins", "Henrik Stenson", 
    "Jairus Byrd", "Jason Peters", "Jayson Werth", "Jeff Gordon", 
    "Jimmie Johnson", "Joe Haden", "Joe Johnson", "Joe Mauer", 
    "Johan Santana", "Julius Peppers", "Justin Verlander", "Kevin Durant", 
    "Kobe Bryant", "Larry Fitzgerald", "LeBron James", "Lewis Hamilton", 
    "Li Na", "Lionel Messi", "Luis SuĂ\241rez", "Mahendra Singh Dhoni", 
    "Manny Pacquiao", "Maria Sharapova", "Mark Teixeira", "Matt Cain", 
    "Matt Holliday", "Matt Kemp", "Matt Ryan", "Matthew Stafford", 
    "Mesut Ă–zil", "Miguel Cabrera", "Neymar", "Novak Djokovic", 
    "Pau Gasol", "Peyton Manning", "Phil Mickelson", "Prince Fielder", 
    "Radamel Falcao", "Rafael Nadal", "Robin van Persie", "Robinson Cano", 
    "Roger Federer", "Rory McIlroy", "Rudy Gay", "Russell Westbrook", 
    "Ryan Howard", "Sebastian Vettel", "Serena Williams", "Sergio AgĂĽero", 
    "Steven Gerrard", "Terrell Suggs", "Tiger Woods", "Tim Lincecum", 
    "Usain Bolt", "Vernon Wells", "Wayne Rooney", "Wladimir Klitschko", 
    "Yaya TourĂ©", "Zach Randolph", "Zack Greinke", "Zlatan IbrahimoviÄ‡"
    ), class = "factor"), Sport = structure(c(5L, 6L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 5L, 
    1L), .Label = c("Baseball", "Basketball", "Boxing", "Cricket", 
    "Football", "Golf", "Racing", "Soccer", "Tennis", "Track"
    ), class = "factor"), Total.Pay = c(2.2e+07, 17700000, 21500000, 
    22900000, 18050000, 26700000, 20400000, 2.3e+07, 18435000, 
    17500000, 20500000, 18750000, 29400000, 24200000, 24200000, 
    21800000, 25300000, 20700000, 23800000, 19800000), Salary.Winnings = structure(c(10L, 
    75L, 44L, 52L, 25L, 48L, 38L, 16L, 27L, 17L, 37L, 29L, 46L, 
    54L, 29L, 32L, 58L, 40L, 54L, 12L), .Label = c("$10,000,000", 
    "$105,000,000", "$11,000,000", "$12,100,000", "$12,500,000", 
    "$13,200,000", "$13,300,000", "$13,500,000", "$13,700,000", 
    "$14,500,000", "$14,700,000", "$14,800,000", "$14,900,000", 
    "$15,100,000", "$15,300,000", "$16,500,000", "$16,800,000", 
    "$17,000,000", "$17,200,000", "$17,300,000", "$17,400,000", 
    "$17,600,000", "$17,800,000", "$17,900,000", "$18,000,000", 
    "$18,300,000", "$18,400,000", "$18,500,000", "$18,700,000", 
    "$18,900,000", "$19,200,000", "$19,300,000", "$19,500,000", 
    "$2,400,000", "$20,000,000", "$20,100,000", "$20,200,000", 
    "$20,300,000", "$20,400,000", "$20,500,000", "$20,700,000", 
    "$200,000", "$21,000,000", "$21,100,000", "$21,200,000", 
    "$21,400,000", "$21,500,000", "$21,700,000", "$21,800,000", 
    "$22,300,000", "$22,500,000", "$22,600,000", "$22,700,000", 
    "$23,000,000", "$23,500,000", "$24,000,000", "$24,400,000", 
    "$25,100,000", "$25,400,000", "$29,000,000", "$30,500,000", 
    "$31,500,000", "$32,400,000", "$36,400,000", "$4,000,000", 
    "$4,200,000", "$4,300,000", "$41,000,000", "$41,700,000", 
    "$42,000,000", "$5,200,000", "$5,600,000", "$52,000,000", 
    "$6,200,000", "$8,700,000"), class = "factor"), Endorsements = structure(c(44L, 
    48L, 33L, 28L, 37L, 35L, 6L, 43L, 30L, 45L, 28L, 37L, 46L, 
    3L, 36L, 15L, 17L, 17L, 47L, 35L), .Label = c("$0", "$1,000,000", 
    "$1,200,000", "$1,500,000", "$1,800,000", "$100,000", "$11,000,000", 
    "$12,000,000", "$14,000,000", "$150,000", "$16,000,000", 
    "$18,000,000", "$19,000,000", "$2,000,000", "$2,500,000", 
    "$20,000,000", "$200,000", "$21,000,000", "$22,000,000", 
    "$23,000,000", "$250,000", "$26,000,000", "$28,000,000", 
    "$3,000,000", "$3,200,000", "$3,500,000", "$30,000,000", 
    "$300,000", "$31,000,000", "$35,000", "$4,000,000", "$4,500,000", 
    "$400,000", "$48,000,000", "$5,000,000", "$5,500,000", "$50,000", 
    "$500,000", "$52,000,000", "$53,000,000", "$55,000,000", 
    "$6,000,000", "$6,500,000", "$7,500,000", "$700,000", "$8,000,000", 
    "$800,000", "$9,000,000"), class = "factor"), Nation = structure(c(24L, 
    2L, 24L, 24L, 6L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 
    24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 6L), .Label = c("Argentina", 
    "Australia", "Brazil", "China", "Colombia", "Dominican Republic", 
    "England", "France", "Germany", "India", "Ivory Coast", "Jamaica", 
    "Mexico", "Netherlands", "Northern Ireland", "Philippines", 
    "Portugal", "Russia", "Serbia", "Spain", "Sweden", "Switzerland", 
    "Ukraine", "United States", "Uruguay", "Venezuela", "Wales"
    ), class = "factor"), Gender = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L), .Label = c("Female", "Male"), class = "factor"), Year.of.birth = c(1983L, 
    1980L, 1982L, 1975L, 1976L, 1982L, 1978L, 1989L, 1984L, 1984L, 
    1981L, 1989L, 1984L, 1980L, 1985L, 1984L, 1978L, 1983L, 1985L, 
    1975L), Birth.Date = structure(c(38L, 20L, 96L, 62L, 90L, 
    23L, 9L, 18L, 82L, 48L, 86L, 64L, 66L, 42L, 87L, 54L, 75L, 
    63L, 12L, 32L), .Label = c("08/04/1986", "1/10/1984", "10/02/1986", 
    "10/10/1974", "11/04/1980", "11/10/1982", "12/11/1988", "13/03/1979", 
    "13/05/1978", "13/05/1983", "14/04/1989", "14/07/1985", "15/01/1979", 
    "15/01/1980", "15/06/1984", "15/10/1988", "16/01/1980", "16/03/1989", 
    "16/06/1970", "16/07/1980", "16/07/1981", "16/07/1989", "16/11/1982", 
    "17/01/1982", "17/05/1985", "17/08/1986", "17/09/1975", "17/12/1978", 
    "18/01/1980", "18/04/1983", "18/07/1990", "18/11/1975", "19/04/1983", 
    "19/04/1987", "19/06/1978", "19/11/1979", "2/06/1988", "2/12/1983", 
    "20/02/1983", "20/03/1984", "20/05/1979", "21/07/1980", "21/08/1986", 
    "21/10/1983", "22/01/1982", "22/05/1987", "22/11/1982", "23/03/1984", 
    "23/08/1978", "23/09/1984", "24/01/1987", "24/02/1977", "24/03/1976", 
    "24/03/1984", "24/06/1987", "24/10/1985", "25/03/1976", "26/02/1982", 
    "26/06/1974", "26/06/1984", "26/09/1981", "27/07/1975", "27/12/1983", 
    "28/02/1989", "28/03/1988", "29/05/1984", "29/06/1981", "29/07/1981", 
    "29/09/1988", "3/01/1981", "3/06/1986", "3/07/1987", "3/10/1981", 
    "30/05/1980", "30/08/1978", "30/12/1975", "30/12/1984", "31/08/1983", 
    "4/05/1989", "4/08/1971", "4/10/1988", "4/11/1984", "5/02/1985", 
    "5/02/1992", "5/04/1976", "5/08/1981", "6/05/1985", "6/07/1980", 
    "6/08/1983", "7/01/1976", "7/01/1985", "7/02/1988", "7/04/1983", 
    "7/07/1981", "7/10/1986", "8/05/1982", "8/08/1981", "8/12/1978", 
    "8/12/1985", "9/05/1984"), class = "factor"), Place.of.Birth = structure(c(19L, 
    1L, 75L, 55L, 76L, 40L, 41L, 58L, 69L, 66L, 36L, 56L, 15L, 
    88L, 27L, 23L, 12L, 75L, 3L, 79L), .Label = c("Adelaide, Australia", 
    "Akron, Ohio", "Aliquippa, Pennsylvania, United States", 
    "Annapolis, Maryland", "Atlanta, Georgia, United States", 
    "Austin, Texas", "Baltimore", "Barcelona, Spain", "Basel, Switzerland", 
    "Belgrade, Serbia", "Bellevue, Washington", "Benton, Arkansas", 
    "BouakĂ©, Ivory Coast", "Boulogne-sur-Mer, France", "Brooklyn, New York City, New York, United States", 
    "Buenos Aires", "Cardiff, Wales", "Chicago, Illinois, United States", 
    "Chico, California, United States", "County Down, Northern Ireland, United Kingdom", 
    "Croxteth, Liverpool, England, United Kingdom", "Cypress, California", 
    "Dallas, Texas, United States", "Dothan, Alabama", "El Cajon, California, United States", 
    "Exton, Pennsylvania, United States", "Forsyth County, North Carolina, United States", 
    "Fort Washington, Maryland, United States", "Fuenlabrada, Spain", 
    "Funchal, Madeira, Portugal", "Gelsenkirchen, Germany", "Gothenburg, Sweden", 
    "Grand Rapids, Michigan, United States", "Guadalajara, Jalisco, Mexico", 
    "Heppenheim, Hesse, Germany", "Houston, United States", "Kannapolis, North Carolina, United States", 
    "Kazakhstan", "Kibawe, Bukidnon, General Santos, Philippines", 
    "Lake Wales, Florida", "Las Vegas Valley, Nevada, United States", 
    "Little Rock, Arkansas", "Long Beach, California", "MĂ©rida, Venezuela", 
    "MalmĂ¶, Sweden", "Manacor, Balearic Islands, Spain", "Manakin-Sabot, Virginia", 
    "Marion, Indiana", "Midwest City, Oklahoma", "Minneapolis", 
    "Minneapolis, Minnesota, United States", "Mogi das Cruzes, Brazil", 
    "New Orleans", "New Orleans, Louisiana, United States", "New York City", 
    "North Charleston, South Carolina", "Nyagan, Russia", "Oklahoma City, Oklahoma, United States", 
    "Ontario, California", "Orlando, Florida", "Oviedo, Asturias, Spain", 
    "Parkersburg, West Virginia", "Pembroke Pines, Florida, United States", 
    "Pequannock Township, New Jersey", "Philadelphia", "Pittsburgh", 
    "Queen City, Texas, United States", "Ranchi, Bihar, India", 
    "Rochester, New York, United States", "Rosario, Santa Fe, Argentina", 
    "Rotterdam, Netherlands", "Saginaw, Michigan, United States", 
    "Saint Paul, Minnesota", "Salto, Uruguay", "San Diego, California, United States", 
    "San Pedro de MacorĂ­s, Dominican Republic", "Santa Marta, Colombia", 
    "Santo Domingo", "Santo Domingo, Dominican Republic", "Shreveport, Louisiana", 
    "Springfield, Illinois", "St. Louis", "Stevenage, Hertfordshire, England, United Kingdom", 
    "Stillwater, Oklahoma", "Tampa, Florida, United States", 
    "Trelawny Parish, Jamaica", "Valencia, Venezuela", "Vallejo, California", 
    "Vallejo, California, United States", "Venezuela, Maracay", 
    "Washington, D.C.", "West Germany, WĂĽrzburg", "Whiston, Merseyside, England, United States", 
    "Wilson, North Carolina, United States", "Wuhan, Hubei, China"
    ), class = "factor"), Height..cm. = c(188L, 183L, 188L, 190L, 
    185L, 211L, 188L, 208L, 196L, 193L, 188L, 198L, 203L, 201L, 
    183L, 211L, 190L, 193L, 180L, 195L)
```

Had to delete few columns because they contain too much data( links to wiki page, description and other not used by me columns)

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(dane)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(dane, 20))`.

Comment: Done as you requested

Comment: to ge rid of the dollar sign, the syntax is this: `gsub("$", "", data)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dataset you provided, does not have the same column names as that in your code.. So I use a subset of the data you provided and it should work for your larger data frame. It's not very clear what you want to plot, so I am using sports and the three columns that have some earnings in it.

A subset of your data:

```
df = structure(list(Sport = structure(c(3L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 1L), .Label = c("Baseball", 
"Basketball", "Football", "Golf"), class = "factor"), Total.Pay = c(2.2e+07, 
17700000, 21500000, 22900000, 18050000, 26700000, 20400000, 2.3e+07, 
18435000, 17500000, 20500000, 18750000, 29400000, 24200000, 24200000, 
21800000, 25300000, 20700000, 23800000, 19800000), Salary.Winnings = structure(c(1L, 
18L, 12L, 15L, 5L, 14L, 10L, 3L, 6L, 4L, 9L, 7L, 13L, 16L, 7L, 
8L, 17L, 11L, 16L, 2L), .Label = c("$14,500,000", "$14,800,000", 
"$16,500,000", "$16,800,000", "$18,000,000", "$18,400,000", "$18,700,000", 
"$19,300,000", "$20,200,000", "$20,300,000", "$20,500,000", "$21,100,000", 
"$21,400,000", "$21,700,000", "$22,600,000", "$23,000,000", "$25,100,000", 
"$8,700,000"), class = "factor"), Endorsements = structure(c(12L, 
16L, 7L, 5L, 10L, 8L, 2L, 11L, 6L, 13L, 5L, 10L, 14L, 1L, 9L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 15L, 8L), .Label = c("$1,200,000", "$100,000", "$2,500,000", 
"$200,000", "$300,000", "$35,000", "$400,000", "$5,000,000", 
"$5,500,000", "$50,000", "$6,500,000", "$7,500,000", "$700,000", 
"$8,000,000", "$800,000", "$9,000,000"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
20L), class = "data.frame")
```

Change the "$" containing ones to numeric:

```
df$Salary.Winnings = as.numeric(gsub("[$,]","",as.character(df$Salary.Winnings)))
df$Endorsements = as.numeric(gsub("[$,]","",as.character(df$Endorsements)))
```

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% pivot_longer(-Sport) %>% 
ggplot(aes(x=Sport,y=value,fill=name)) + geom_col()
```

[image]